# Trouble making a running total in C

Tags: c

I'm new at programming, new on this site too, so hello...
I'm attempting to obtain a running total for integers one thru 10, but I'm getting gibberish answers and I just can't understand why.
To attempt to find out what was going wrong, I added the

```
printf(" running total is %d\n", sum);
```

line to the while loop, but just got more of the same nonsense...
please see http://codepad.org/UxEw6pFU for the results....

I'm sure this has a blindingly obvious solution...I'm just too dumb to see it though!
anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)      {

    int count,sum,square;           
    int upto=10;                 

    count = 0;                
    square = 0;                 

    while (++count < upto)   {   
        square = count * count;
        printf("square of %d is %d",count,square);     
        sum =square + sum;
        printf(" running total is %d\n", sum);
    }

    printf("overall total of squares of integers 1 thru 10 is %d\n", sum);           

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In the future, please select your code and click the `101010` button to give it proper formatting.

Comment: also please choose an answer as the 'correct' one by clicking the big tick mark on the left of it. It is considered bad etiquette to not do that

Comment: no - I was not telling him off. I was telling him what to do once he was satisfied. I did not know the whole accept thing when I first posted - and got grilled later.

Comment: @pm100..thanks for the advice..I don't see it as telling off lol. In fact, it's not that easy to know what the etiquette is, so thanks...@Tyler..Thanks..I'll look for that button next time I ask a Q..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to initialize sum to 0.

**EDIT** As others have stated after the fact, the reason you're seeing garbage is because `sum` isn't initialized and contains whatever is in memory.  It can be anything, and your use of it with `sum = square + sum` is going to add square to the uninitialized value.

Comment: @blaxjax: In pure C, local variables aren't automatically initialized to anything in particular. In this case, `sum` was equal to whatever happened to be in that place in memory, which is not what you wanted.

Comment: @quixoto - thank you for adding to my answer and improving it rather than duplicating it.

Comment: Thanks SB, and everyone else that answered. SB, I have ticked your response because it was the first, and because it worked. The answer was obvious, as I guessed, but it could have taken me a week to work it out by myself.....next time, I won't make this mistake, but another one instead!

Answer (score 1):

You are never initializing the value of `sum`.

The first time your code runs

```
sum = square + sum;
```

The value of `sum` (on the right side) is an arbitrary number because it has not been initialized. Therefore, the resulting value of `sum` (on the left side) is that arbitrary number plus `square`.

Simply add a `sum = 0` statement like you have for `count` and `square` already.

Answer (score 1):

Right off the bat, you do not initialize 'sum' to anything.

edit: A cleaned up version, though depending on compiler, you might need to enforce C99 mode, otherwise older compilers might not support initial declarations in the `for` loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    const int COUNT_MAX = 10;
    int sum = 0;

    for ( int i = 1; i <= COUNT_MAX; ++i )
    {
        sum += i*i;
    }

    printf("The sum of squares from 1 to 10 is: %d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1: I was thinking of writing a "cleaner" version, but then I saw this. (a) Declaring and initializing one variable per line. (b) The "idiomatic" `for` loop reads much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `sum` with `0`, otherwise it contains arbitrary data:

```
sum = 0;
```

See: http://codepad.org/e8pziVHm

Answer (score 0):

sum is not initialized

Answer (score 0):

You should do :

```
sum=0;
```

and remove

```
square=0;
```